# String list in columns jasper ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a report fed by a java object, this object contains a list of strings, If I drag the list it prints the data, but when on a detail band with 4 columns it does not respect the columns, it just prints on the length of the field. How do I get around this.  I need the data on the list to be printed row by row and spread out in the 4 columns.

[image]
A link to the image, is not really clear on the question due to its size. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvS9N.png

And if I can print it without the brackets “[]” that would be a big plus.

Thanks for reading

Comment: It looks like you might need to add a grouping band for numerosGuias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved via a subreport, with columns instead of the list directly because that seems to be the issue, I don't know if it is the most optima solution but it worked for me.